# parsing a string with python regex optional named groups

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am struggling with python named group re

I have the following string: `"blah blah id=xyz, blah blah foo bar=zxy] blah baz=a}"`
terminating chars are: `,]}`

and I would like to get out named dict using regex pattern that looks like this:

`{'id': 'xyz', 'foo bar': 'zxy', 'baz': 'a'}` groups should be optional

I was able to hit it without named groups and including termination characters but I am sure there is a way how to do it fully in regexp and be more elegant ... it just eludes me
any help would be welcome

my current solution is using folowing pregmatch:

`(id=.* ?[, }\]] |baz=.* ?[, }\]] |foo bar=.* ?[, }\]])`

it works but requires significant postprocessing (string splitting and striping)

```py
         for i in ae2:
            key, value = i.split('=', 1)
            altevent2[key] = value.strip('},] ')
```

Also, it would be cool to get rid of whitespace/unprintable chars but only when they are at the start/end of the value

if at all possible it should require no postprocessing - I need a lot of performance

Edit1: list if dict 'IDs' is known in advance, for this case it would be 'id','foo bar','baz'

Comment: Why do you expect  `{'id': 'xyz', 'foo bar': 'zxy', 'baz': 'a'}` and not `{'id': 'xyz', 'bar': 'zxy', 'baz': 'a'}`? Your syntax rules are difficult to infer from the example given. Also, your syntax doesn't look regular, so I doubt a regex by itself can parse it.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone those names are placeholders - names are often longer and duplicated at last word

Comment: oh, you know the keys to get already; much easier then...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re.split()` method to split the initial string from your endpoints and search for matching with your keys in your dict, like the code.

```
import re
    
ex = "blah blah id=xyz, blah blah foo bar=zxy] blah baz=a}"
dict_keys = ["id", "foo bar", "baz"]

end = re.split(", |] |}", ex)  # ['blah blah id=xyz', ' blah blah foo bar=zxy', ' blah baz=a', '']

result = {}

for i in dict_keys:
    for j in end:
        if i in j:
            result[i] = j.partition("=")[2]
```

OBs: I try to avoid the "2 for", but I could't find a way to do that.

Comment: I have updated question with my current solution requiring only one loop of postprocessing :         for i in ae2:
            key, value = i.split('=', 1)
            altevent2[key] = value.strip('},] ') I would like to have no postprocessing if possible

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
s = "blah blah id=xyz, blah blah foo bar=zxy] blah baz=a}"
re.findall('(id|foo bar|baz)=([^,}\]]+)', s)
```

Comment: Just wrap this in `dict` to get a dictionary result, and you need a `+` in your second capturing group: `dict(re.findall(r'(id|foo bar|baz)=([^,}\]]+)', s))`

Comment: @jdaz Thanks for correct the code. But can we just wrap it by `dict`? It will remain only last one value for each key.